# Flutter with RevenueCat

Tags: flutter, revenuecat

I was following a tutorial but got cut off as something does work.

I am using revenuecat as my subscription handler howver i have encountered a problem where I cant update the bool value though i made a function.

The idea is that if the entitlement that i gave (no_ads) gives a result back in the form of entitlement.no_ads, the "adsOff = false" bool will then be converted to "adsOff = true".

this is the function incharge of altering the bool "adsOff" to false or true.

```
  Future<void> presentAd() async {

    CustomerInfo customerInfo = await Purchases.getCustomerInfo();
    print('this is customer info ${customerInfo}');
    final entitlements = customerInfo.entitlements.active.values.toList();
    final liveEntitlement =
    entitlements.isEmpty ? Entitlement.free : Entitlement.no_ads;
    print('current entitlement: $liveEntitlement');
    if(liveEntitlement == Entitlement.no_ads) {
      setState(() {
        adsOff = true;
      });
    }else {
      setState(() {
        adsOff = false;
      });
    }
  }
```

the boolean value

```
class Weights extends StatefulWidget {
   Weights({super.key});

  @override
  State<Weights> createState() => _WeightsState();
}

class _WeightsState extends State<Weights> {
  bool adsOff = false;
```

thanks again for any help, im sure its going to be something very obvious
cheers

Comment: Is function presentad() inside Weights class?

Comment: yes, it is inside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **`Statefull widgets`** if you want to access any variable you need to add **`widget.`** syntax. It should look like this: **`widget.[your variable]`**
try below:

```
Future<void> presentAd() async {
    CustomerInfo customerInfo = await Purchases.getCustomerInfo();
    print('this is customer info ${customerInfo}');
    final entitlements = customerInfo.entitlements.active.values.toList();
    final liveEntitlement =
    entitlements.isEmpty ? Entitlement.free : Entitlement.no_ads;
    print('current entitlement: $liveEntitlement');
    if(liveEntitlement == Entitlement.no_ads) {
      setState(() {
// ADDED [WIDGET.] BEFORE 
        widget.adsOff = true;
      });
    }else {
      setState(() {
// ADDED [WIDGET.] BEFORE 
        widget.adsOff = false;
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: cheers, did something along the lines of this